# Traverse nested object and change values

Tags: javascript, jquery

I've got an object containing user-data alongside some dates. I'd like to format these dates (as they are delivered like this `2015-02-13T18:25:37+01:00`).

I'd like to have the values of the object changed in-place but how can I do this?

I traverse the object like this:

```
$.each(myObject, formatDates)
    var isDate = function(value) {
        return  (value!==null && !isNaN(new Date(value)))
    }

    var formatDates = function(key, value){
        if (isDate(value)) {
            // Change value here
            console.log("key:" + key + " value: " + value)
        }

        // Recursive into child objects
        if (value !== null && typeof value === "object") {
            $.each(value, formatDates)
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use this

```
function iterate(obj) {
        for (var property in obj) {
            if (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) {
                if (typeof obj[property] == "object") {
                    iterate(obj[property]);
                } else {
                  // do your date thing
                }
            }
        }
        return obj;
    }

iterate(object)
```